# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, frameworks, entity

I have two tables Application_User and Application_User_Access. Application_User_Access table is having a foreign key constraint with Application_User table.

When I delete a record in Application_User table, I receive "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" exception.

This happens in ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web application. I want to delete all the child records in this case and finally delete the parent record. How to implement this?

Answer (score 12):

You can implement a cascading delete for `Application_User_Access` table. For this you need to modify your DB schema a little bit. Concretely remove the previous reference from the `Application_User_Access` to the `Application_User` table and add a new one:

```
--not sure about the column names though

ALTER TABLE Application_User_Access
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Application_User_Access_Application_User
FOREIGN KEY (used_id)
REFERENCES Application_User(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Notice that `ON DELETE CASCADE` thing. It means that whenever the primary key record is deleted the foreign key record referencing it will be removed as well.

Comment: In the partial class of my context, I added OnSavingChanges method with the below code,

Comment: Well, this is a possible approach, but it has a little flaw. `Application_User_Access` records does not make sense without `Application_User`. This is not a business rule, it's a matter of the DB integrity. That's why I'd say that modifying the constraint by adding the cascade delete is a little bit better here. But after all you should go with the approach you find most comfortable.