# Asp.net Cascading delete into Gridview_Rowdeleting event

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, cascading-deletes

I have a problem that to deleting record from database. I want to delete with using Id but it has been exist other tables as foreign key. That's why I need to delete with extension.
I need to delete record from 3 tables which are Conferences, Conferences_Rewivers, Topics.
My codes like that but it throws error because of it doesn't delete records from all tables. How can I fix it?

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDeleting1(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ---\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = --; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete FROM Conferences where Id = @Id";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Conferences_Rewivers where fk_Conferences = @Id";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Topics where fk_Conferences = @Id";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        BindGridView();
    }
```

BindGridView

```
 if(Session["user"] != null)
        {
            user = Session["user"] as User;
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Conferences.Id, Conferences.conferenceName, Conferences.conferenceDate , Conferences.conferencePlace, Conferences.submissionDueDate , Conferences.category, Conferences.status, Conferences.conferenceDescription from Conferences inner join Users on Conferences.fk_Users = Users.Id where Users.Id = @UserId", conn);
        SqlParameter prm = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", user.Id);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();

        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that solution of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895411/728795?

Answer (score 0):

First you delete foreign key tables(Conferences_Rewivers,Topics) after that you can delete  main table(primary key table i.e Conferences)